# How can I configure sass with ionic.

Tags: ionic-framework

I am using the default ionic seed application, I have ran the setup 
command `ionic setup sass.`
I run `ionic serve`, this should be watching for sass changes but it's not.
I tried to run `gulp watch` but I am getting an error.`Error: Cannot find module 'semver'`

Comment: Did you install sass using ruby?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using sudo ionic setup sass

You might not have had sufficient security privileges, thus not allowing sass to be setup properly. Using sudo will allow the user to act as a superuser and let sass setup correctly.

This worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you elaborate as to _why_ this helps?

Comment: Because the user might not have had sufficient security privileges, thus not allowing sass to be setup properly. Using sudo will allow the user to act as a superuser and let sass setup correctly.

Comment: Awesome: If you edit that into your answer, you'll get my vote!

Answer (score 2):

**First you need to run this command**  `ionic setup sass` when you run this command create a `scss folder` in `www folder` in scss folder here is `style.scss` file.
and `@import` this file in `scss/ionic.app.scss` path.

`@import "www/scss/style.scss"` in `scss/ionic.app.scss` path.

Try this I hope this is work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Please delete the 'node_modules' folder in the project directory and re-run 
'npm install'. This worked for me .

Comment: What is the status of this question does this worked

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have changed your index.html to include the relevant css files, as the one previously will no longer be used if you want to use the .min.css one generated by sass.

Answer (score 0):

If removing the node_modules and running npm install doesn't work you can try installing gulp then install sass

```
npm install -g gulp
ionic setup sass
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sass via Ruby:

- Install Ruby
- Install Sass: `npm install -g node-sass`
- On ionic project (v2) type: `npm rebuild node-sass`

So whenever you touch sass file(s), you can just rebuild the sass: `npm rebuild node-sass` if not, it's OK, just continue normal `ionic serve`

**Remark**: ionic2 requires sass

Answer (score 0):

**Using Sass in ionic project**
if you are using windows node cli. goto in your project by

c:\projectname

after

c:\projectname>ionic setup sass

done

http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/sass.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will setup the sass in your ionic project.

```
ionic setup sass
```

If gulp is not setup then run this command first

```
npm install gulp -g
```